# jquery $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Tags: jquery

I would like some help about this case :

Actually, I have a form and I try to put different rules to manage It. The form doesn't work because I have this error on my navigator :

```
TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

...result = $.validator.methods[method].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters )
```

I looked on the HTML screen in firebug and I saw this :

```
<head>
<script id="undefined" type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js">
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-NQP3WH">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/jquery.placeholder.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/jquery.cluetip.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/library/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/script.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/form-devis.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/snippet/js/index.js" type="text/javascript">
<link media="all" href="/snippet/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" href="/snippet/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" href="/snippet/css/jquery.cluetip.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" href="" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" href="/snippet/branding/colis-urgent/added.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Envoi colis Urgent / express </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/library/jquery.validate.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<style type="text/css">
</head>
```

I then suspect a bad order of .JS included. I compared with a other form that works perfectly :

```
#if($ieOldBrowser)
    #set($d = $jsExternalSet.addAll([
                     '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js',
                     '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.js',
                     '/js/library/respond.js'
                    ]))
#else
    #set($d = $jsExternalSet.addAll([
                     '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
                     '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'
                    ]))
#end

    #set($d = $jsCommonSet.addAll([ 
                     '/js/library/jquery.validate.js',
                     '/js/library/jquery.placeholder.js', 
                     '/js/library/jquery.cluetip.js',
                     '/js/library/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js',
                     '/js/inscription.js.vtl',
                     '/js/form-contact-mail.js',
                     '/js/form-devis.js',
                     '/js/popup-address.js',
                     '/js/sha1.js',
                     '/js/login.js',
                     '/js/form-login.js',
                     '/js/tooltip.js',
                     '/js/script.js'
                    ]))
```

But apparently It is not that. Please If you have an idea to suggest me, tell me ...

Ale.

Comment: I'd suspect that the `method` is undefined, meaning  - on the validated form the class that you're using doesn't exist within the `$.validator.methods` array. Just open the `validate.js` and put `console.log(method, $.validator.methods[method])` before the erroreous line to find the culprit.

Comment: sorry in this moment I use console.log(method,$.validator.methods[method]); but I don't really know how to investigate after in order to see all the logs blah-blah

Comment: In the console one of the entries should be "something, `undefined`"